# Solving $Q {(1-E)}^A + E^{AQ} < 1$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation

Let $\lambda_1 = Q {(1-E)}^A$ and $\lambda_2 = 1 - E^{AQ}$.

I'd like to find the conditions where $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2$, i.e. solve: $Q {(1-E)}^A + E^{AQ} < 1$, subject to: $0 \le E \le 1$; $A > 0$; $Q > 0$.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Solve for $A$ or $Q$?

Comment: The general form, ideally, so some function of $A, Q, E$.

Comment: From simulation, I think the solution is $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2$ when $Q < 1$, with no dependence on $E$ or $A$. However, I'd still appreciate any help with proof.

Comment: @jessexknight The expression is strictly decreasing in $A$ when $0 < E < 1$.